# Codecommit cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am newbie to AWS bear with me any mistake. I have two aws accounts( let say "Developer", "Producer"). Developer has a code repo in his Codecommit repository. I want to commit changes to the Producer's account Codecommit repository. Is it possible to push the code from Developer's account to Producer's account repo directly or any easy way?.

I have read "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html" document but this is not exactly what I want. Please help me this was a headache for me so long.

To elaborate more I have following figure. whenever certain changes occur in the prod branch in the Developer account, It should be cloned to prod branch in the Production account
[see the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKWp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The document you're looking at describes how to give cross-account access to a repository, which is not what you need in this case.

You should simply fetch the code from the developer account, then login in the producer account and push the code there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my task is to commit developer's code to production repository without the mentioned method.

Comment: @jan18 you can't